# Python multithreading web crawling

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing

I have a simple [web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) which crawls ~4 (specific) sites per second. If I run the script in two different Python IDEs I can double the speed because both programs runs the code with ~4 crawls per second.
Why does my code runs slower than it could be? Or is it faster because I use a silly way to make my script use multithreading/multiprocessing by using two different IDEs at the same time?

I use Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Your approach is less silly than you might think, because prior to Python 3 this was the official approach for doing multiprocessing :)

Comment: To clarify, you want to know why the program itself runs at the same speed whether it is the only one running or if there are two on the go, so by having two on the go the overall result is twice as fast - correct?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - correct

Comment: In that case I don't think this is so much about python as it is about [why do programs not use all the cpu available?](https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjv1qepjurOAhVJbxQKHZ8cBoMQPAgD#hl=en&q=why+do+programs+not+use+all+the+cpu+available%3F) but I honestly don't understand it myself so I can't really help here.

Comment: @SturmGhost When parallelizing tasks, there is a meaningful distinction between CPU bound work and other kinds of time intensive work. If the work that you are doing is slow because of e.g. network latency, you can speed up the work by firing off lots of requests at once and waiting for them all to complete. The total time taken is the time taken by the longest request, rather than the sum of the times taken by each request, as would be the case if you dispatched the requests sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great task for a Pool of worker threads.

See: [Python: The Multiprocessing Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about threading, as explained in the comments.

Now there is a solution for your program:

```
import requests
import threading

class Crawler:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def crawl(self):
        page = self.session.get(url)
        # Do your crawling here

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f: # Assuming you use a file with a list of URLs
    for url in f:
        while(threading.active_count() > 20): # Use 20 threads
            time.sleep(0.1)
        c = Crawler(url)
        t = threading.Thread(target = c.crawl())
```

Please note that `threading.active_count()` also counts the main thread.

And also, that you should use timeouts in HTTP requests.